# Score Counters and Reset Functions in Vanilla JavaScript Hangman

Tags: javascript, function, random, counter

I've already had one questions regarding this game answered, but I keep getting stuck up on keeping track of my "wins" and "losses" and then reseting my random word after a win or a loss. Here is what I have so far:

```js
var guess; //user guess
var letters = []; //correctly guessed letters
var wrongLetters = []; //incorrectly guessed letters
var counter = 7; //counts correct letters
var losses = 0;
var wins = 0;

document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = losses;
document.getElementById("wins").innerHTML = wins;

var wordList = ["cat", "dog", "wolf", "laser", "apple"]; //FILL LIST LATER!!

//randomly chooses a word from wordList
var word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

//choosen word is replaced with
function start() {
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    letters[i] = "__";
  }

  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = letters.join(" ");
  console.log(word);
}


//checks if letter is in the word or not
function checkLetter() {
  document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    guess = event.key.toLowerCase();
    var found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (guess === word[i]) {
        letters[i] = guess;
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = letters.join(" ");
        found = true;
      }
    }
    //wrong letters go into the wrongLetters array and are displayed
    if (found) return;
    if (wrongLetters.indexOf(guess) < 0) {
      wrongLetters.push(guess);
      document.getElementById("wrongGuesses").innerHTML = wrongLetters.join(" ");
      counter--;
      console.log(counter);
      //+1 to the losses if 7 words are missed
      if (counter === 0) {
        document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = losses + 1;
        console.log(losses);
        confirm("play again?"); {
          counter = 7;
          letters = [];
          wrongLetters = [];
          start();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//need the counter to subtract 1 with every wrong guess
//when counter hits zero losses = losses + 1
//make a wins var that adds 1 when word is guessed
//reset if either are 


start();
checkLetter();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hangman</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hangman!</h1>
  <span>Just start writing to play.</span>

  <p>
    <font size="+3"><span id="answer"></span></font>
  </p>
  <p id="counter"></p>
  <p id="wrongGuesses"></p>
  <p>Wins: <span id="wins"></span></p>
  <p>Losses: <span id="losses"></span></p>

</body>

</html>
```

The counter is ALMOST working! It seems to be counting down from 7 and adding 1 to the losses when it reaches zero as it should; however, the count displayed is off (even though the count logged to the console seems right).

Another issue is that this "losses" count won't continue to add past 1 even if the counter resets and hits 0 again.

Also, when I try to grab a new random word after the player fails to answer the first, the game chooses the same word as it did before.

I feel like most of these issues have to deal with the scope of my variables, but none of the reworking I try seems to have any affect (if it doesn't make things worse). I know I'm asking a lot here, but if anyone could even point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Adding losses++ under the confirm("play again") seems to have fixed the issue with the losses not adding up, but for some reason I can't get the word to change... I tried putting the random generator inside of the start function, but that just made things worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with fixing the random word.

The variable `word` needs to be accessed by several functions so it need to be defined on a scope outside the current functions. But you want to set it new each time inside the `start()` function. You can do that by declaring the variable outside of the function where it is now, but *set* it inside the function. You should also reset the counter here.

```
//randomly chooses a word from wordList
var word

//choosen word is replaced with
function start() {
    word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];
    counter = 7;
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        letters[i] = "__";
    }

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = letters.join(" ");
    console.log(word);
}
```

The counter isn't working, because it doesn't look like you're updating the html when the counter changes. You need something like this with each guess:

```
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;

counter--;
console.log(counter);
```

The losses aren't incrementing because you are only changing the HTML but not the losses variable (kind of the opposite of the above). You need both:

```
losses++
document.getElementById("losses").innerHTML = losses;
```

There is also one subtly problem -- you are catching all the `keyups` including an enter keyup when you first start. You can catch only letters with something like this:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    // don't catch numbers, punctuation, enter, etc.
    if (!(event.which <= 90 && event.which >= 65)) return
```

Comment: Now I'm just having trouble figuring out how to let the game know the user go the word correct. It was simple to get the word wrong with counter counting down from 7, hitting 0 triggers a loss. Obviously the counter has to be > 0, but it also needs to somehow check that the full word has been filled in. I guess I'm just not too sure how to express that

Comment: Yep, that seems like the next challenge. Maybe something built around `if(letters.join('') == word){ }` will work.

Comment: Ah good thinking! I tried if (guess == word) and it didn't work, but I'll keep at it!